# Flexbox doesn't work when flexDirection is set to "row"

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm playing around with Flexbox, but I can't seem to figure out why FlexDirection doesn't work when set to 'row'.

```
export default function WorkoutScreen() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <AppText>Heading</AppText>

            <View style={styles.sets}>


                <AppText>Reps</AppText>

                <FontAwesome name="minus-square" size={48} color="purple" />

                <AppText>9</AppText>
                <FontAwesome name="plus-square" size={48} color="pink" />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    sets: {
        flex: 1,
        **flexDirection: "row",**
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 100,
    },
});
```

I've been scratching my head about what I'm doing wrong, any tip to fix this would be greatly appreciated! I'm trying an ios simulator on Iphone pro 12 max.

[image: When flexDirection is set to "row"]
[image: When flexDirection is set to column, it works as expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally figured this out. If you check the [Text documentation][1], it says

> The  element is unique relative to layout: everything inside is
> no longer using the Flexbox layout but using text layout. This means
> that elements inside of a  are no longer rectangles, but wrap
> when they see the end of the line.

So basically I had to wrap the texts inside View tags.
[1]: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text